# есть массив состоящий из объектов как создать на его основе массив состоящий из объектов в которых есть только первых три поля name, lastName

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, деструктурирующее-присваивание

```
const characters = [
  {
    name: "Елена",
    lastName: "Гилберт",
    age: 17, 
    gender: "woman",
    status: "human"
  },
  {
    name: "Кэролайн",
    lastName: "Форбс",
    age: 17,
    gender: "woman",
    status: "human"
  },
  {
    name: "Аларик",
    lastName: "Зальцман",
    age: 31,
    gender: "man",
    status: "human"
  },
  {
    name: "Дэймон",
    lastName: "Сальваторе",
    age: 156,
    gender: "man",
    status: "vampire"
  },
  {
    name: "Ребекка",
    lastName: "Майклсон",
    age: 1089,
    gender: "woman",
    status: "vempire"
  },
  {
    name: "Клаус",
    lastName: "Майклсон",
    age: 1093,
    gender: "man",
    status: "vampire"
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const characters = [
  {
    name: "Елена",
    lastName: "Гилберт",
    age: 17, 
    gender: "woman",
    status: "human"
  },
  {
    name: "Кэролайн",
    lastName: "Форбс",
    age: 17,
    gender: "woman",
    status: "human"
  },
];

const characters2 = characters.map(
  ({ name, lastName, age }) => ({ name, lastName, age })
);

console.log(characters2);
```

Comment: спасибо большое